# AngularJS grid no data message

Tags: angularjs

I was just wondering if this a way to display "No data available" instead of grid if json returned by the controller is empty? In the code below gridData stores the json returned by the controller

```
<div class="row">

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Format</b></td>
                <td><b>Day of Month</b></td>
                <td><b>Day of Week</b></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in gridData">
                <td>{{i.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{i.DayofMonth}}</td>
                <td>{{i.DayofWeek}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete('{{i.Id}}')">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover " ng-if="gridData.length > 0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Format</b></td>
                    <td><b>Day of Month</b></td>
                    <td><b>Day of Week</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="i in gridData">
                    <td>{{i.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.DayofMonth}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.DayofWeek}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete('{{i.Id}}')">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <div ng-if="gridData.length === 0">No data available</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-switch`

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-switch="gridData">
    <div ng-switch-when="gridDataIsEmpty()">No data available</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="!gridDataisEmpty()"> <!-- Normal table Code --> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```